# Are there data sets that contain math problems (and preferably their solutions) at the college level

Tags: data-request

I was looking for data sets that contain math problems at the college level and above.

It would be great if the data sets:

1. Have each problem by topic such as: basic calculus, analysis, etc.
2. Have solutions for the math problems

Any reference, links, tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like khanacademy.org, ck12.org, ixl.com, and googling would find tons of these? There are even platforms that generate "random" questions and answers: http://www.imathas.com/ and http://webwork.maa.org/ for example